# How do I reverse engineer iisres.dll?

Tags: ida

I have this file called [issrel.dll](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3uwecqwv0sfpirp/iisres.dll).
But I can't simply put it into IDA PRO, because it does not recognize it correctly .

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to disassemble in it. Presumably, IDA Pro scans only for code segments; there aren't any in this DLL.

My own tool reports this

```
...
NumberOfRvaAndSizes         00000010
   2. Resource Directory       VirtualAddress 00001000; Size 0002EF10

== PE sections ==
Name  '.rsrc'
PhysAdr/VirtSize     0002EF10
VirtualAddress       00001000 -> 00401000..0042FF0F
SizeOfRawData        0002F000
PointerToRawData     00000200
PointerToRelocations 00000000
PointerToLinenumbers 00000000
NumberOfRelocations  0000
NumberOfLinenumbers  0000
Characteristics      40000040 -> Initialized data | Readable

== RVA's ==
2. Resource Directory
VirtualAddress 00001000 -> inside section '.rsrc' at 00000000
Size           0002EF10
```

and as you can see, all it contains are *resources*. Google for a Windows resource editor if you want to know what it contains (a cursory glance with a basic hex editor shows 'the usual': a VERSION_INFO block, some strings, EVNT tables, and a rather nice PNG image).

---

(Edit) http://pedump.me/cfebba297b36cbb7c52c5ff592f6f0fe/ lists its contents in a basic yet very comprehensive overview. It agrees with me: the "disasm" view says: "invalid VA 0x400000".

Comment: "disasm" view says: "invalid VA 0x400000" <-- invalid virtual address? But how to fix that? pedump.me says it has MUI for example. How can that be useful to me?

Comment: "invalid VA" is most likely "invalid Virtual Address". The PE header says "ImageBase 00400000" and "BaseOfCode 00001000", but there is no code there (because there isn't any). How do you mean, "useful to you"? I don't know what's useful to you. Google turned up http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1aa1350-41a0-4490-9ae3-9b4520aeb9d4/faq-common-questions-for-etw-and-windows-event-log?forum=etw, which seems to be a description of what "WEVT_TEMPLATE" is used for.

Comment: .. and googling for "MUI" gives me http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912683.aspx, which says it's Multi-Language User Interface stuff (although the hex dump suggests your file contains only one language--say hello, Microsoft Bloatware).

Comment: @Jongware: that is how MUI is intended to work. And certainly better than it used to be in the past.